# How to add Confidence Interval from linear regression to a plot with multiple groups

Tags: r, continuous-integration, linear-regression

I have done linear regression on the data I've collected for my master thesis. I have created scatter plots with three categories on the x axis for three different groups. I want to add Confidence Intervals (CI) for each group and each category, but I can't figure out how to.

```
ClutchvsAge = ggplot(All_Pippi, aes(Clutch, Age, colour = Treatment)) + 
 geom_point() + geom_jitter(width=0.2) +
 theme(axis.text=element_text(size=11),
       axis.title=element_text(size=12)) + 
   labs(x= "Clutch Number", y = "Age") + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3)) + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c("#228B22", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

[image: This is what is produced]

I would like to use `geom_errorbar`, but I can't figure out how to get the CI for each treatment and clutch into `ymin` and `ymax`.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for the wrong terms. Try searching for confidence bands. It hard to know what kind of error bar might appear on a scatter plot with regression lines.

Comment: Take a look at the `ggeffects` package ...